# Alchemy-Websockets - WebSocketClient Path

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm new to stackoverflow.

I'm currently working on a WebSocket project and using a component called Alchemy-Websockets.

My question is when I trying to use Alchemy.WebSocketClient class like this :

```
var aClient = new WebSocketClient("ws://172.28.1.103:8100");
```

I got a FormatException error.

the documentation here : 
http://alchemywebsockets.net/docs/class_alchemy_1_1_web_socket_client.html

didn't show any sample code.

so, could anyone gives me some help here?

TKS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jack here, maintainer of Alchemy. (We need to update our autogenerated docs.)

Try appending a channel to the end of your connection, like this:

```
var aClient = new WebSocketClient("ws://172.28.1.103:8100/channel");
```

Note the /channel on the end. The value can be anything. You can see an example in our integration tests: https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/blob/master/test/Integration/Alchemy/ClientServer.cs